# java8 a list of map reduce by key

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of maps as below.

And I want to group the entry sets by key, 
if a key non exist, fill 0 instead.

```
    List<Map<String, Double>> props = Lists.newArrayList();
    Map<String, Double> m1 =  Maps.newHashMap();
    m1.put("a", 0.1);
    m1.put("b", 0.5);
    m1.put("c", 0.6);

    Map<String, Double> m2 =  Maps.newHashMap();
    m2.put("a", 0.3);
    m2.put("d", 0.1);

    Map<String, Double> m3 = Maps.newHashMap();
    m3.put("a", 0.2);

    props.add(m1); props.add(m2); props.add(m3);
```

Expected result:

```
{a=[0.1, 0.3, 0.2], b=[0.5, 0, 0], c=[0.6,0,0], d=[0,0.1,0]}
```

I got an idea:

1. find all distinct keys
2. fill every map of missing keys with value 0
3. groupby key, values mapping to a list

Any good ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: @GCP each map will not contain all the keys. If the key is missing, we should fill 0 instead of nothing. See my expected answer. Expected type is Map<String, List[Double]>. It likes organizing data to a table. And table index is all the keys.

Answer (score 6):

It can be done in single line lamda and stream except the case *fill every map of missing keys with value 0*

```
  Map<String, List<Double>> collect = Stream.of(m1, m2, m3)
                   .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                   .collect(groupingBy(
                            Map.Entry::getKey,
                            mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList()))
                    );

  System.out.println(collect);
```

And this will produce the output as

```
{a=[0.1, 0.3, 0.2], b=[0.5], c=[0.6], d=[0.1]}
```

Here static factory methods `Collectors.groupingBy()` is used to group the concatenated Entries of all maps by the Key (`classifier`) and mapping method (`collector`).

If its the obvious case you must to *fill every map of missing keys with value 0* then there is several way of doing that. One that @abhi stated in other answer. Along with his idea I would like to do that this way

```
  Set<String> allKeys = Sets.newHashSet();
  props.forEach(prop -> allKeys.addAll(prop.keySet()));
  allKeys.forEach(k -> props.forEach(m -> m.putIfAbsent(k, 0.0)));
```

Infact this will modify your original maps with `allKeys` having `0` as value `ifNotPresent`. If this modification causes you problem you can prefer to copy your maps to have separate collections.

This will ensure your desired output

```
{a=[0.1, 0.3, 0.2], b=[0.5, 0.0, 0.0], c=[0.6, 0.0, 0.0], d=[0.0, 0.1, 0.0]}
```

**Note:** You can find this article interesting about [Grouping using Java 8 streams](https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/grouping-using-java-8-streams)

Answer (score 1):

The code is not very efficient, but it gets the job done.

```
    List<Map<String, Double>> props = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Double> m1 =  new HashMap<>();
    m1.put("a", 0.1);
    m1.put("b", 0.5);
    m1.put("c", 0.6);

    Map<String, Double> m2 =  new HashMap<>();
    m2.put("a", 0.3);
    m2.put("d", 0.1);

    Map<String, Double> m3 = new HashMap<>();
    m3.put("a", 0.2);

    props.add(m1); 
    props.add(m2); 
    props.add(m3);

    Set<String> allKeys = new HashSet<>();

    for (Map<String, Double> prop : props) {
        allKeys.addAll(prop.keySet());
    }
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map<String, Double> prop : props) {
        for (String key : allKeys) {
            if(!result.containsKey(key)){
                result.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            if(!prop.containsKey(key)){
                prop.put(key, 0.0);
            }
            Double propValue = prop.get(key);
            result.get(key).add(propValue);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

You basically want to use a `Set<String>` then iterate through all the maps to get their `keys`, then when you have all the keys you need to iterate through all the maps, check if the key exists, if it doesn't then add it to the map and now you can add it to the `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>>` because you know that the key exists for this map

Comment: Well done. Same as my idea. I wonder if using java8, this work can be implemented by just one line of code.

Comment: 1 line of code isn't always the best solution, it might make it hard to read. The problem is that you have no idea which keys exists, so you need to iterate through all the maps to get the keys. The prop iteration might have been possible to solve with streams, but i haven't looked enough into it to give you a qualified answer

Answer (score 1):

java 8 surely does reduce the number of lines, but not to one line of code in your case

```
    Set<String> keys = Sets.newHashSet();
    props.forEach(prop -> keys.addAll(prop.keySet()));

    Map<String, List<Double>> result = Maps.newHashMap();
    keys.forEach(key -> result.put(key, new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(props.size(), 0D))));
    props.forEach(prop -> prop.forEach((key, value) -> result.get(key).set(props.indexOf(prop), value)));

    System.out.println(result);
```